# Android Studio runs full [assemble] instead of specific configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have moved some peace of code to a newly created module and added some dependencies to that module. And now when I press on Run button in AS it starts running [assemble] command instead of [assembleMyFlavorDebug]. But I almost never run other configurations so don't want to build full project

Comment: Try Build-> Select Build Variant

Comment: I chose Build Variant, but still AS runs [assemble]